# Match rows between dataframe and replace with a value in another column of the second dataframe

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The first contains a column containing IDs and various other columns while the other contains mapping information for these IDs (ID to Name).

I want to replace the ID in the first dataframe with the Name from the other dataframe.

I am able to do this

```
for(id in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df1$X[df1$X %in% df2$ID[id]] <- df2$Name[id]
}
```

This works so long as I do not have repeating IDs in the mapping file such as this:

```
ID,Name  
MSTRG.11187,gng7.S  
MSTRG.11187,Novel
```

But this occurs quite a lot. I think my previous code will work if I can get rid of any rows from the mapping file which contain the word Novel in them. I am just struggling to do this. I have tried this :

```
data = data %>% group_by(GeneID) %>% filter(!("Novel" %in% Gene_Name))
```

But in the previous example of the repeating IDs with different names, it gets rid of the row with gng7.S as well as getting rid of the row with Novel. I'd like to do this but keep the row with gng7.S and only get rid of the row with Novel.

I'm thinking this might be something to do with the group_by part.

Thanks,
S

Edit: Here are some example dataframes

```
df1=data.frame(X=c("MSTRG.199","MSTRG.18989","MSTRG.8890","MSTRG.7767"))

df2=data.frame(ID=c("MSTRG.18989","MSTRG.18989","MSTRG.8890","MSTRG.7767", "MSTRG.199"),Name=c("gng7.S", "Novel", "Novel","cdc20", "Novel"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data. It is possible that you can use some join operation in R to avoid the for loop.

Comment: data = data %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(!("Novel" %in% Gene_Name))

This seems to do the trick for the mapping file and the for loop is working but it is taking a very long time. (files are 60k + rows long).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully clear whether any appearances of `"Novel"` should be removed from `df2` or only in cases of duplicate `ID`. The second case is quite tricky, so I propose a `data.table` solution which I'm more fluent in (and Q isn't explicitely tagged with `dplyr`)

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c("MSTRG.199", "MSTRG.18989", "MSTRG.8890", "MSTRG.7767"))
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("MSTRG.18989", "MSTRG.18989", "MSTRG.8890", "MSTRG.7767", "MSTRG.199"),
  Name = c("gng7.S", "Novel", "Novel", "cdc20", "Novel"))

library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(df1)
DT2 <- data.table(df2)

# case 1
# remove all rows with Name == Novel before joining
DT2[!Name %in% c("Novel")][DT1, on = .(ID = X)]
```

> ```
>             ID   Name  N
> 1:   MSTRG.199     NA NA
> 2: MSTRG.18989 gng7.S  2
> 3:  MSTRG.8890     NA NA
> 4:  MSTRG.7767  cdc20  1
> ```

```
# case 2
# remove Novel in cases of duplicate appearances of ID
DT2[, N := .N, by = ID][!(N > 1L & Name %in% "Novel")][, N := NULL][DT1, on = .(ID = X)]
```

> ```
>             ID   Name
> 1:   MSTRG.199  Novel
> 2: MSTRG.18989 gng7.S
> 3:  MSTRG.8890  Novel
> 4:  MSTRG.7767  cdc20
> ```